# MobileConnect: Query that will show OptInStatus for all contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, mobileconnect, status

I need to see the OptInStatus for all contacts in MobileConnect. I've tried querying off of the SMSSubscriptionLog data view, but I'm not very strong with SQL. Here is the query I've been using, but it's been returning incorrect Status. For example, I can see that a number is double-opted in via MobileConnect, but their status will show as a SingleOptIn. Outside of this query, if there's a simpler way to get this data, please let me know!

```
ssl.MobileSubscriptionID as SubscriberKey,
ssl.SubscriptionDefinitionID as SubscriptionDefinitionID,
ssl.MobileNumber,
CASE WHEN ssl.OptInStatusID = 0 Then 'NotOptedIn'
     WHEN ssl.OptInStatusID = 1 THEN 'SingleOptIn'
     WHEN ssl.OptInStatusID = 2 THEN 'DoubleOptIn'
     WHEN ssl.OptInStatusID = 10 Then 'DeletingNotOptedIn'
     WHEN ssl.OptInStatusID = 11 THEN 'DeletingOptInPending'
     WHEN ssl.OptInStatusID = 12 THEN 'DeletingOptedIn'
     ELSE 'Unknown'
END as Status,
CASE WHEN ssl.OptInStatusID = 2 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END as SMSOptIn,
ssl.LogDate,
ssl.OptInDate,ssl.OptOutDate 
from _SMSSubscriptionLog ssl
```

Comment: there is not a double opt in vs single in status, the status would be opted in, opted out and optin pending??

Answer (score 0):

In this [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_sms_subscription_log.htm&type=5) optinstatusid =

> OptInStatusID Key
>
> NotOptedIn = 0
>
> OptInPending = 1
>
> OptedIn = 2
>
> DeletingNotOptedIn = 10
>
> DeletingOptInPending = 11
>
> DeletingOptedIn = 12